# What does 'picture' mean in the passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does ***picture*** mean in the passage? I looked it up in the dictionaries to no avail. I could not find a proper definition to fit with the context.

> Now the colorful city, Colombia's second largest, is part of an
> altogether brighter ***picture***. A rigorous peace effort has quelled
> the armed conflict, while a recent report ranked it as the
> fastest-growing metropolitan economy in Latin America.

[How giant outdoor escalators transformed a Colombian neighborhood](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/colombia-medellin-neighborhood/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

In this context it means the general situation. See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/picture sense 6: *took a hard look at his financial picture*.

The writer is saying that the situation in this city is much better.

Comment: How about 'colorful'? Does it mean 'having bright colours or a lot of different colours' or 'interesting and exciting'?

Comment: Medellin does appear to have some brightly coloured buildings, but the metaphorical sense is probably intended too.

Comment: The second sentence in the quoted passage makes it clear that it is talking about the economic and criminal situation rather than the colour.

Answer (score 1):

the definition of "picture" is the general situation in a place, organization etc. You can find the word in Longman.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the collective situation and circumstances in that city.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/picture

Comment: Welcome to ELL. I hope you like the place and decide to visit often. You might want to [take the tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) or to read the [Contributor's guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4783/91457). The guide has a lot of helpful information on how best to ask, and answer, questions here on ELL.